How to update first element in array object
My document is
{
  _id: 1,
  age: "young",
  hobby: [
  {
    vehicle: "car",
    velocity: "fast"
  },
  {
    vehicle: "motorcycle",
    velocity: "fast"
  }
  ]
}

My goal is: when age became old, first hobby became "slow" but others remain "fast"
My code is:
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
  Query.query(where("_id").is("1")),
    Update.update("age", "old")
      .set("hobby.$[elem].velocity", "slow")
      .filterArray(Criteria.where("elem").is(0)), "collection name")

But it does not work, result is:
{
  _id: 1,
  age: "old",
  hobby: [
  {
    vehicle: "car",
    velocity: "fast"  <<--- not slow
  },
  {
    vehicle: "motorcycle",
    velocity: "fast"
  }
  ]
}

I could achieve my goal with
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
  Query.query(where("_id").is("1111")),
    Update.update("age", "old")
      .set("hobby.$[elem].velocity", "slow")
      .filterArray(Criteria.where("elem.vehicle").is("car")), "collection name")

But I want modify FIRST array element, not car array element

If you always only want to update the first element, then you can refer to the first element with 0. The standard query would be:
db.collection.update({ _id: 1111 },
{
  $set: {
    "age": "old",
    "hobby.0.velocity": "slow"  // note the '0'
  }
})

Mongo Playground
I don't know spring but I presume the query would be something like:
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
  Query.query(where("_id").is("1111")),
    Update.update("age", "old")
      .set("hobby.0.velocity", "slow")  // note the '0'


Thank you, you answer is ok, but now I see my problem is a bit different. I will modify my query now

ok, this question is rolled back t original and accepted and new question is raised
